# Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/test.py] No module named 'boto3'. How to pip install into airflow container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, airflow

I have the following hierarchy:

```
-airflow
  -dags
    -test.py
  -deployment
    -dockerfile
    -docker compose
  -scripts
  -requirements.txt
```

The `test.py` file uses functions from the `scripts` directory. Some of the scripts have external import statements, like `import boto3`. I assume this is where the problem is, because when I run the airflow webserver I can see that all the DAGs which don't require those external packages load up, but the DAGs which do require them fail to load with:
`Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/test.py] No module named 'boto3'`
The `docker compose` file looks something like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  webserver:
    build: .
```

I tried to add something like this to my `dockerfile`:

```
FROM puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9

WORKDIR /airflow
COPY requirements.txt /airflow
RUN pip install -U pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But the packages don't seem to get installed. How can I install my `requirements.txt` whenever I boot up the webserver (docker compose up)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be as easy as...

```
WORKDIR /airflow
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You may also have to instruct the  Docker build step. I think `docker-compose build .` or `docker-compose up --no-cache`... but that's based on a loose memory

Comment: Thanks for the help @Mike Taylor. I changed my `Makefile` to run `docker-compose --build -d airflow ` and that works. However now it's not recognizing the `requirements.txt` file. At least I can get pip to install the requirements now. Any additional help on how to get the `requirements.txt` to work would be great!

Comment: Not a worry, I can't tell you how requirements.txt is failing, given the information I have... here's the snippet from the last project I was on that coordinated with Docker and requirements


ADD ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --no-cache -r requirements.txt


But that is quite old so..... Maybe you do need to expressly copy requirements.txt to /airflow/requirements.txt

Comment: Sorry no fun styling in comments

Comment: Haha no worries about the styling! I got it to work with the `requirements.txt` file. I scratched the `depoyment` directory and put all the docker stuff and makefile in the root directory which made it able to read the file. From my understanding because docker was trying to build the image from the deployment folder, the `requirements` file was outside its context. Thanks for the help!